# Send csv Data from power bi each month to user's Email Using power Automate

Tags: csv, powerbi, power-automate

I'm trying to set a flow that exports data from a table in power bi and send it as a file.csv every 1st of the month to the user who triggers the flow.

I used power automate but can't seem to add a recurrent option to it :

[image: power automate flow]

Does anybody knows if it's possible to do so?

Thank you so much,
Regards,
Mona

Comment: Can you confirm the comment "every 1st of the month to the user who triggers the flow"?  I ask because a user triggering the flow and having it run on the 1st of the month are both triggers.  From what you've got, you're really just wanting the user to trigger the flow, correct?  Therefore, it could be any day of the month.

Comment: Thank you @Skin for your reply. I want to achieve the folowing : once the user clicks on the button in the power bi report, they will receive the csv data each month by email without them going each time to triguer the flow. it will be like a subscription if you want. Please don't hesitate if you need more clarification. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to think differently. You need separate flows, one to subscribe and another to run on recurrence to process each subscription. They’re separate flows with different purposes.

Comment: thank you Skin :) I'll try to do that :D